# left and right sliding with ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ng-animate, ngroute

I would like to build a horizontally sliding website using AngularJS (Material), but I'm having trouble configuring the animations. What I want is to slide a page left if the clicked menu link is right from the current page. I have set up ngRoute to change the views:

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/home", {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            })
            .when("/test", {
                templateUrl: 'test.html',
                controller: 'testController'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" })
    })
    .controller('navController', function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
        $scope.$route = $route;
        $scope.$location = $location;
        $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
    });
```

With the following `index.html`:

```
<body ng-cloak>
    <div layout="column">
            <md-toolbar id="navbar" flex="grow" ng-controller="navController">
                <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                    <md-button ng-href="#home">Home</md-button>
                    <md-button ng-href="#test">Test</md-button>                        
                </div>
            </md-toolbar>           
        <md-content class="view" ng-view></md-content>
    </div>   
</body>
```

I want to animate the views using ngAnimate CSS classes, but I have no idea how to conditionally set the classes based on the menu structure, e.g. setting either `.view.ng-enter.left` or `.view.ng-enter.right`. You can find the site [here](http://sjors.hijgenaar.eu).

Comment: `md-tabs` has sliding pages. Could you not use that? https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

Comment: Yes I could and I will, thank you!

Comment: @camden_kid The only problem is the routing is gone, any solution that does include ngRoute?

Comment: Does this help - http://codepen.io/dstnation/pen/yyvjvP? It uses ui-router but it's the same concept.